# How can i access the control in fragment in a tabed layout in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, nullpointerexception

I create a project in android and use page view and fragment to create a tab layout and I create a control in each fragment (3 fragment)
Now the problem is Here :

In the `main activity class` in the `oncreate()` method I want to set text to a text view and use this code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("fgdfgdfgdf dfgdf");}
```

the application running without any error but in the emulator I get this error `**!unfortunately Test is Stopping**`

and in the log cat i get this!

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference

I think my way to access the control in the fragment is wrong
please help me that so important to me

Comment: From the `onCreate()` method of an activity you only can get view elements on the activity XML. I guess that in your case the TextView `textView1` is in the fragments, right?

Comment: @dmananes Yes
How can access the textview in fragment in main activity

Comment: @TheChamp Yes How can access the textview in fragment in main activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `onCreate()` method of an activity you only can get view elements on the activity XML.

You can do this on the Fragment class instead of the Activity:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setText("fgdfgdfgdf dfgdf");
    return view;
}
```

Comment: tanx i will try it and comment for you

Comment: Very very very very  Tanks to you @Thechamp
You Saved Me

Comment: @thechamp
Can you take me your Email Address Here I will Get in trouble in future